# Are all dungeon-based word walls obvious at the end of the dungeon?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So at the end of some of my first dungeons in Skyrim, I found word walls to learn shouts that were painfully hard to miss. They usually were right on the main path and glowed in your face when you got near them.

However lately I've been noticing an distinct lack of word walls in many dungeons along major quest chains. Are some word walls hidden in the dungeon that I might have completely missed? Or are all word walls nearly impossible to miss due to their position and prominence?

Comment: I fear that the answers to this would be subjective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I remember from my "get all the words" run, no. There's one dungeon with the word wall easily missable because the wall is actually outside the dungeon itself but it's a secondary quest linked dungeon. The exit is actually on a ledge you cannot really reach above the entrance. The wall is too far away from the exit for you to get the music telling you it's nearby so it's easy to just go away from there without learning the world.

Also, during the main quest, one dungeon, the one where you need to use a shout to pass some timed doors, the word wall is kinda in the middle of the dungeon a little out of the way but if you really are into exploring most of the places you visit, you shouldn't miss it.

All in all, the only word you can really miss is the one on a dungeon in the main quest which is explicitly described as impossible to reach through normal means but the word is right in your face on the way. You cannot revisit the place later.

Comment: I believe the main quest dungeon you mention is the 'Retrieving the Horn' one for the Greybeards.

Comment: yup, confirming this.

Comment: I missed the one outside Ysgramor's tomb the first time through, I happened to go back and then stumbled on it.  Its outside the main dungeon.

Comment: It sounds like the first one you mentioned is at Forelhost(SE of Riften) and part of the side quest Siege on the Dragon Cult. It can also be a radiant location for the Alteration Ritual Spell  http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Forelhost

Answer (score 1):

Word walls are very hard to miss in major quest chains, especially those in dungeons. They're big and for some weird reason, you hear chants when your are near one. They also seem to be conveniently placed near the end of the dungeon, near the boss.

Note however, that not all major quests will have you encounter a word wall, even the main quest. Also, there are many word walls like the [one found near here (link)](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Kilkreath_Ruins) that may not be part of a major quest at all, and you may miss it if you haven't been exploring.

If you're looking to have all dragon shouts, [Arngeir](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Arngeir) will provide you word wall locations, sending you on a quest to learn the dragon shout on that wall. Note that some dragon shouts are only learned from a certain quest - most of them from the main quest line. If you also use a shout on a location (usually inside a dungeon), you may get (too frequently, in my case) a ["Letter from a Friend"](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Letter_from_a_Friend), also providing a word wall location and sending you on a quest to learn the dragon shout on that wall.

If reading a guide does not break the roleplaying experience for you, there is a list of all dragon shouts and where to get them here: http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragon_Shouts

Comment: I love the music played near the word walls!

Answer (score 0):

The second one.

I think you'll find that most word walls outside of the ones in the starter dungeons, are in secondary quest dungeons instead of main storyline ones. (Indeed, some are in some dungeons that no quest will take you in.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, if you use your shouts in cities you will be guided by an anonymous note of a dungeon with a wall.

Comment: @GmNoob After the Greybeards like you, you can also ask them and they'll tell you where one is.